# Facebook marketing api upload video to AdVideo

Tags: php, facebook-marketing-api

I'm new to FB marketing API.
I'm using php to create a function which handles the creation of the adVideo:

```
 public function getUploadVideo() {
    Api::init($this->appId, $this->appSecret,$this->token);
    $video = new Advideo(null, 'act_' . $this->adAccountId);
    $video->{AdVideoFields::SOURCE} = 'https://s3-us-west 2 .amazonaws.com /unittest-tvpage-com/testsuite/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4';
    $video->{AdVideoFields::NAME} = 'test_video';
    $x = $video->create();
```

The video I'm using does not need any permissions and it can be directly downloaded.
When I run the function I get the following error message:
Type: FacebookAds\Exception\Exception
Code: 26
Message: couldn't open file "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/unittest-tvpage-com/testsuite/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"

Any ideas why the file could not be opened?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read How [do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make sure you will get appropriate answers.

Comment: did you able to find out?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/advideos

To add the video using the url is `file_url` not `source`. The `source` parameter is used for uploading a file.